# Add/Remove rows dynamically in a table in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to add/remove rows in a table dynamically. I have javascript function to add and remove the rows. But, I want the delete button beside every single row so that I can delete a particular row.

ANd I want to add a row only if the first row is completely filled.

function to remove row

```
 function removeRowFromTable()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('tblSample');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 2) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
```

function to add rows:

```
function addRow(tableID) {

            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

            var rowCount = table.rows.length;
            var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

            var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
            var element1 = document.createElement("input");
            element1.type = "text";
            cell1.appendChild(element1);

            var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
            var element2 = document.createElement("input");
            element2.type = "text";
            cell2.appendChild(element2);
        }
```

my table:

```
<table id="tableId">
<tr><td>Host Name</td><td>Directory</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text"/></td><td><input type="text"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="+" onclick="addRow(tableId)"/></td>
<td><input type="button" value="-" onclick="removeRowFromTable()"/></td></tr>
</table>
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you put a delete button on each row, then:

```
<tr>
  <td><input type="button" value="Delete row" onclick="deleteRow(this)">
  <td><input type="text">
  <td><input type="text">
</tr>
```

And the deleteRow function can be:

```
function deleteRow(el) {

  // while there are parents, keep going until reach TR 
  while (el.parentNode && el.tagName.toLowerCase() != 'tr') {
    el = el.parentNode;
  }

  // If el has a parentNode it must be a TR, so delete it
  // Don't delte if only 3 rows left in table
  if (el.parentNode && el.parentNode.rows.length > 3) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
  }
}
```

BTW, if all your rows have the same content, it will be much faster to add a row by cloning an existing row:

```
function addRow(tableID) {
  var table = document.getElementById(tableID);

  if (!table) return;

  var newRow = table.rows[1].cloneNode(true);

  // Now get the inputs and modify their names 
  var inputs = newRow.getElementsByTagName('input');

  for (var i=0, iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    // Update inputs[i]
  }

  // Add the new row to the tBody (required for IE)
  var tBody = table.tBodies[0];
  tBody.insertBefore(newRow, tBody.lastChild);
}
```

Comment: content will be different..BTW, I will be saving the data to DB and pulling from it to show the content..so,I think cloning might be a risk in long run..will be considering your suggestion of cloning for time being for sure..

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid a lot of cross browser headaches by using jquery. Here is a sample.

http://jsfiddle.net/piyushjain7/gKJEs/

Answer (score 2):

Javascript has this really useful function called [deleteRow](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_deleterow.asp) where if you know the index you are deleting from, you can simply input that number, and then it'll delete that specific row (index's starting at 0 - tbl.rows.length).

I also found a nice [example](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/dynamically-add-remove-rows-in-html-table-using-javascript/) that uses it in action. You can adjust it to fit your needs though (although his uses checkboxes which might be a lot cleaner than just making a button next to every single row). I don't encourage you to blatantly copy the code so if there is anything that confuses you, please let us know. Hope this helps.

EDIT: I didn't see you wanted to add rows after you found out the last row was completely filled. I'll update my answer when I figure that out. However, the basic idea of that is to check if the `<td>` tag has text in it (perhaps check if the text inside the tag isn't a blank or if there is a `<td>` tag at all and then if it isn't empty, make a new `<tr>` element else don't.

Comment: I really do like the checkbox style..but, unfortunately I have to go without checkboxes..probably, i need to check for the value of last textbox to null and further go from there...

Answer (score 2):

See http://jsfiddle.net/9gnAx/

HTML & JavaScript (body):

```
<table id="tableId">
    <tr>
        <th>Host Name</th>
        <th>Directory</th>
        <td><input class="add" type="button" value="+" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td></td>
        <td><input class="add" type="button" value="+" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
    var els=getElementsByClassName("add","tableId");
    for(var i=0;i<els.length;i++){
        els[i].onclick=addRow;
    }
    els[0].onclick();
    })();
</script>
```

CSS (head):

```
.add,.del{
    width:25px;
}
```

JavaScript (head):

```
function getElementsByClassName(c,el){
    if(typeof el=='string'){el=document.getElementById(el);}
    if(!el){el=document;}
    if(el.getElementsByClassName){return el.getElementsByClassName(c);}
    var arr=[],
        allEls=el.getElementsByTagName('*');
    for(var i=0;i<allEls.length;i++){
        if(allEls[i].className.split(' ').indexOf(c)>-1){arr.push(allEls[i])}
    }
    return arr;
}
function killMe(el){
    return el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}
function getParentByTagName(el,tag){
    tag=tag.toLowerCase();
    while(el.nodeName.toLowerCase()!=tag){
        el=el.parentNode;
    }
    return el;
}
function delRow(){
    killMe(getParentByTagName(this,'tr'));
}
function addRow() {
    var table = getParentByTagName(this,'table')
    var lastInputs=table.rows.length>2?
        table.rows[table.rows.length-2].getElementsByTagName('input'):[];
    for(var i=0;i<lastInputs.length-1;i++){
        if(lastInputs[i].value==''){return false;}
    }
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount-1);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "text";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "text";
    cell2.appendChild(element2);

    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var element3 = document.createElement("input");
    element3.type = "button";
    element3.className="del";
    element3.value='-';
    element3.onclick=delRow;
    cell3.appendChild(element3);
}
```

**Update:**

RobG has made me realize that `getParentByTagName` throws an error if there isn't any parent with the `nodeName` passed.

If you want a more general `getParentByTagName`, which doesn't throw errors, you can use

```
function getParentByTagName(el,tag){
    tag=tag.toLowerCase();
    while(el&&el.nodeName.toLowerCase()!=tag){
        el=el.parentNode;
    }
    return el||null;
}
```

And when you call the function you should check if the result is `null`.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9gnAx/1/

Comment: The *getParentByTagName* function should check that the current node has a parent node, otherwise it will throw an error if a parent with the required tag isn't found, e.g. `while (el.parentNode && el.nodeName.toLowerCase() != tag)`, then at the end you have to check that you have a node with the right tag name.